# Python vs Java performace: brute force equation solver

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I wrote a program in Python and in Java to search for the smallest integer solution of the equation:

$$a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5=e^5$$

(expected output is \$133^5 + 110^5 + 84^5 + 27^5 = 144^5\$)

Powers and roots are either computed directly ("direct calculation" method) or computed and stored in an array ("power lookup" method). Fifth powers are looked up like `n5 = fifth_power[n]`. Fifth power *root* is computed using a binary search in array 'fifth_power`.

I am running it on NetBeans if it matters. It takes:

- 30 s (Python, direct)
- 20 s (Python, lookup)
- 5.6 s (Java, direct)
- 0.8 s (Java, lookup)

Is there a way to boost Python performance? I am not looking for better math (sieving of some kind). I am looking for better implementation of "for each combination of a,b,c,d compute some of their powers, check if the sum is a perfect power. If it is - print the result".

Is it expected that Python runs some 20 times slower than Java?

**Python 3.5**

```
from array import *
import math
import time

#PYTHON, BRUTEFORCE : ~30 s
millis1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
keep_searching = True
a=1
result=""
while(keep_searching):
    a+=1
    for b in range(1,a+1):
        for c in range(1,b+1):
            for d in range(1,c+1):
                sum=math.pow(a,5)+math.pow(b,5)+math.pow(c,5)+math.pow(d,5)
                root = math.pow(sum,0.2)
                e = round(root)


                e5 = math.pow(e,5)               

                if(e5==sum):
                    result="{}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 = {}^5".format(int(a),int(b), int(c),int(d), int(e))
                    keep_searching = False
                    millis2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

print(result)
print("Found solution in {} ms".format(millis2-millis1))

#PYTHON, PRECOMPUTE POWERS: ~20 s
millis3 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))  
#fifth_power #175 is enough
size=176
fifth_power = [None] * size
for i in range(size):
    fifth_power[i]=long(math.pow(i,5))

millis4 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))   

#returns  value if it is a perfect power (32 returns 2)  
#returns -1 if between perfect powers, -2 if greater than max value in array, -3 if smaller than min value in array

def check_perfect_power(number, min, max, fifth_power):


    current=int((min+max)/2)
    while(max>=min):
        if(number==fifth_power[current]):
            return current
        elif(number>fifth_power[current]):
            min=current+1
            current=int((max+min)/2)
        else:
            max=current-1
            current=int((max+min)/2)

    if(min>=len(fifth_power)):        
        return -2
    if(max<0):
        return -3

    return -1   

keep_searching = True
a=0
result=""
while(keep_searching):
    a+=1
    for b in range(1,a+1):
        for c in range(1,b+1):
            for d in range(1,c+1):
                mymax=min(int(a*1.32)+1, size-1)
                e=check_perfect_power(fifth_power[a]+fifth_power[b]+fifth_power[c]+fifth_power[d], a, mymax, fifth_power)
                if(e>0):
                    result="{}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 = {}^5".format(int(a),int(b), int(c),int(d), int(e))
                    keep_searching = False
                    millis5 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

print(result)
print("Populated in {} ms, find solution in {} ms".format(millis4-millis3,millis5-millis4))
```

Comment: Obvious question: Did you implement it in the same way for both Java and Python?

Comment: I did. http://pastebin.com/G4V3fHnD So, is this performance difference expected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672857/is-python-slower-than-java-c & http://www.snaplogic.com/blog/python-vs-java-an-update-to-a-subjective-speed-comparison/

Comment: On my machine for bruteforce approach: Py: 58s Rust 1.7s C++: 1.3s F# 2.4s. My recommendation: if you do a lot of numerics, don't use python.

Comment: ... And haskell: 1.7s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious possible improvement for both languages is storing the values to the fifth power (But I'm going to focus on python here).

In python, `while` is a keyword and does not need parenthesis. Also, global lookup of methods is slower than local  lookup, so I would define `pow = math.pow`

```
pow = math.pow
while keep_searching:
    a += 1
    a5 = pow(a, 5)
    for b in range(1, a+1):
        b5 = pow(b, 5)
        for c in range(1, b+1):
            sum_begin = a5 + b5 + pow(c, 5)
            for d in range(1, c+1):
                sum = sum_begin + pow(d, 5)
                ...
```

Also note that python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends putting spaces around operators and after commas in argument lists (I applied those rules in the code above).

Note that `str.format` does not care what it's parameters are. It will just call `str` on them and use that. So no need to call `int` on your parameters (they are already ints anyway).

Comment: Python Power lookup stores fifth powers in an array. It Computes `n^5` by calling `arr[n]` and it computes `n^(1/5)` by a binary search within '`arr`.

Comment: @Stepan Not sure I missed some code or your edit added it. The way it is now, yes your array approach is better. However, storing the intermediate results is also a valid (and easy) improvement on your other method.

Answer (score 0):

C++ bruteforce ~3 s, C++ reference lookup - 0.25 s.

This code has several problems:
(1) `math.pow(a,5)` is way slower than `a**5`

(2) It calculates a^5 each time d changes. Rather it should be

```
for c in range(1,b+1):
    a5b5c5=a5b5+c**5 #c^5 is incremented and a partial sum a^5+b^5+c^5 is calculated
```

(3) Lists and lookup work blazing fast in C++ (due to the way pointers work), but not in Python. Use `set` instead.

Adding fifth powers to a `set` and checking if a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5 is a number in the set is the way to go in Python. With these tweaks code executes in 2 seconds and is faster than the original implementation in C++.